# Dynamic Update value on click counter Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I created a Post page where i want to update value on click on like or dislike .I created a fiddle for this

```
Fiddle:- [https://jsfiddle.net/anujsphinx/k017gsz8/][1]
```

.When i click on like then Like counter will increase and when i click on dislike then dislike counter will increase.

Comment: Where are the update functions defined in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have two function to add and remove,

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="post" ng-repeat="post in posts">
      <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
      <a href="#" ng-click="add(post)">like</a> ({{post.like}})
      <a href="#" ng-click="remove(post)">Dislike</a> ({{post.dislike}})
    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
 $scope.add = function(post) {
    post.like +=1;

  }
  $scope.remove = function(post) {
    post.dislike +=1;
  }
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/k017gsz8/2/)**